# change name of network adaptor in .inf file

Tags: windows, networking, adapter, device-driver, inf

I want to install network driver and I don't have any problem with that but when i install driver in

> Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections

I see my network with this name :

> Local Area Connection 2(2-3-4-5....)

I want to change this name but i don't know how !

I try for change that in .inf file but only change Description and etc...

how can i change this name ? i must change that in .inf file or something else ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumeration is controlled by the OS. It adds a serial number to distinguish between similar devices. Either you have an additional LAN connection or your registry isn't clean and contains remnants of older installations that weren't properly cleaned (e.g. you replaced your network card without unistall). You can attempt to resolve the issue by using one of the registry cleanup utilities that can be found in the internet or by manually searching the registry for an obsolete LAN drivers installation and remove them (careful with that, you can crush your system). In any case, this shouldn't have any effect on the functionality.